# WARN Failed to send SSL Close message(Kafka SSL configuration issue)

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I have done broker and client configuration on same node.

When `ssl.client.auth=none` it works fine but whenever I change that property to "required", `ssl.client.auth=required` and enabled `security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL` then it gives me an issue on producer side.

```
[2017-12-13 11:06:56,106] WARN Failed to send SSL Close message  (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer)
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.flush(SslTransportLayer.java:194)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.close(SslTransportLayer.java:161)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.close(KafkaChannel.java:45)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.close(Selector.java:442)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:310)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:256)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:216)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:128)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Its resolved.This issue comes when  signed certificate of the server did not match with client keystore. We need to generate client keystore and import the the signed certificate of the server to client keystore.

Comment: Could you please better describe the steps to get it? I am using the same keystore in server and client and having `SSH Handshake failed`, passing: `-X security.protocol=ssl -X ssl.key.location=/certs/docker.kafka.server.keystore.pem -X ssl.key.password=apassword -X ssl.certificate.location=/certs/cert-signed -X ssl.ca.location=/certs/docker.kafka.server.keystore.pem`

Answer (score -3):

As mentioned in the comments, the answer was found by the asker:

> Its resolved.This issue comes when signed certificate of the server
> did not match with client keystore. We need to generate client
> keystore and import the the signed certificate of the server to client
> keystore.